Auto-import suggestions not coming up in VS Code 1.88.0
I have installed the necessary libraries for the MUI but when I type a basic component like Typograhy it does not come up in the intellisense. Rather it shows @mui/icons-material. Please see below images.


This was previously working fine until I update the VSCode to the latest version.
Is anyone facing the same issue ?

@starball: doesn't work for me. I have NPM Intellisense extension installed. Still it does not work form me in VS Code

VS Code 1.88 "broke" some auto-import stuff. This is tracked in issue ticket 1.88.0 update broke JS Auto Import functionality #58113. More accurate is to say that the builtin TypeScript language-support extension of VS Code 1.88, which uses TypeScript 5.4, has the issue of TS 5.4, No auto-import from aliased symbol from ts files in js files #57740, which is fixed by Pull Request fix type import check for default-import/re-export in js files #57778, for which backporting to TS 5.4 got missed. The backport has now been made in TS 5.4.5, and the backport will be picked up in VS Code 1.88.1, which has now been released.
In the meantime, you can temporarily switch to the nightly TypeScript language-support extension: ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next, which has the fix (source). If you can't get that to work, you also have the option to temporarily roll back the builtin TypeScript language features extension (search "@builtin typescript" in the Extensions View), or install VS Code 1.87.2.
The @mui/material-specific issue ticket is at [material-ui] Component import suggestion not appearing in VS Code #41802.

Thanks for the answer. Yes I can confirm after updating to the latest release v1.88.1, it fixes the auto import issue.

Version 1.88 breaks it, tried version 1.87 and it works like a charm!

I think so too. This was working fine and then I did the update and it's not working anymore

This is an issue with the V1.88.0 release. I have raised the issue in here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/210013

I temporarily installed the 'JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly' extension since the current version VSCode (1.88) have a problem with auto import.
It currently works:
Screenshot picture
Update: VSCode 1.88.1 fixed the problem
